# get path from txt file

Tags: batch-file

Imagine I have a txt file with a path like:

```
c:\programs\SRC_CODE\
```

How can I do a .bat file that open the txt file and get the string in order to set a variable witht the path catched from the txt?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have at least two possible options. You can either use `set` and input redirection:

```
set /p myPath=<mypath.txt>nul
```

where `set /p` will prompt for the path and the `<mypath.txt` will actually work as if the contents of the text file where input directly.

You also can use the `for` command which can iterate over lines in a text file:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (mypath.txt) do set myPath=%%x
```

Both methods actually have slightly different semantics on files with multiple lines. The first variant will store the first line of the file in the variable, the `for` variant will use the last line. Shouldn't matter for single-line files, though. Oh, and it could happen that the first variant might output an empty line; I've added a redirect to `nul` to void that.